# Script n curl POSTs from n lines of txt file & conditionally save output for HTTP request response "200 OK"

Tags: shell-script, grep, curl, xargs, python3

Given this cURL "POST" request:

```
$ curl -i -s -k -X $'POST' \
-H $'Host: api.host.it' \
-H $'Content-Length: 205' \
-H $'Sec-Ch-Ua: \"Chromium\";v=\"93\", \" Not;A Brand\";v=\"99\"' \
-H $'Messageid: 9d6dd58d2df24d0aa410245a' \
-H $'Sessionid: ada9e560ed204e85a25e5475' \
-H $'Devicetype: ANDROID' \
-H $'Interactiondate-Date: 2021-09-27' \
-H $'Interactiondate-Time: 20:32:37.758' \
-H $'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0' \
-H $'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36' \
-H $'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' \
-H $'Accept: application/json' \
-H $'Sourcesystem: WEB' \
-H $'Businessid: bbc0a98dc23a4a84968c42e4' \
-H $'Channel: HOSTWEBCO' \
-H $'Transactionid: 3F941666A8414D3C874AC77B' \
-H $'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: \"Linux\"' -H $'Origin: https://www.host.com' \
-H $'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site' \
-H $'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' \
-H $'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty' \
-H $'Referer: https://www.host.com/' \
-H $'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
-H $'Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' \
-H $'Connection: close' \
--data-binary $'{\"mount\":25,
                 \"Method\":\"SA\",
                 \"redirectUrlKo\":\"https://www.host.com/scarica?esito=KO\",
                 \"redirectUrlOk\":\"https://www.host.com/scarica?esito=OK\",
                 \"toMsisdn\":\"PARAMETER\",
                 \"txReqDescription\":\"scarica Online\"}' \
$'https://api.host.com/api/charge/public/init'
```

I need to create a Bash, or Python script that executes the cURL command for every line inside file `numbers.txt`, taking each line as input for the PARAMETER place-holder shown inside the cURL `--data-binary` option. Following each `curl` request, output should be directed to file `output.txt` only when the HTTP request response code is "200 OK".

I know that cURL accept file input using `--data@file.txt` but I have other fields before that and it won't work.

Comment: No, only `PARAMETER` has to be fetched from line inside file `numbers.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the shell script below, I address your 3 requirements:

- read successive values of `PARAMETER` from a file `numbers.txt`, where they are listed one value to a line.
- for each retrieved value of `PARAMETER` test whether your HTTP server request return code "200"
- append successive outputs of cURL to `output.txt` provided HTTP return code is "200 OK"

I did not modify your syntax as far as quoting marks and escaped quotes are concerned. This may be use-case or otherwise specific to your environment and I cannot test it. Place the following shell script in a file, `myscript.sh` and make the file executable with
terminal cmd: `chmod ug+x myscript.sh`:

```
$ cat myscript.sh
```

*[output]*

```
#!/usr/bin/sh    
output="$(/usr/bin/date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)""_output.txt"
while read -r dyn_param; do
    set -- -isk \
    -X 'POST' \
    -H 'Host: api.host.it' \
    -H 'Content-Length: 205' \
    -H 'Sec-Ch-Ua: \"Chromium\";v=\"93\", \" Not;A Brand\";v=\"99\"' \
    -H 'Messageid: 9d6dd58d2df24d0aa410245a' \
    -H 'Sessionid: ada9e560ed204e85a25e5475' \
    -H 'Devicetype: ANDROID' \
    -H 'Interactiondate-Date: 2021-09-27' \
    -H 'Interactiondate-Time: 20:32:37.758' \
    -H 'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0' \
    -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' \
    -H 'Accept: application/json' \
    -H 'Sourcesystem: WEB' \
    -H 'Businessid: bbc0a98dc23a4a84968c42e4' \
    -H 'Channel: HOSTWEBCO' \
    -H 'Transactionid: 3F941666A8414D3C874AC77B' \
    -H 'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: \"Linux\"' \
    -H 'Origin: https://www.host.com' \
    -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site' \
    -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' \
    -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty' \
    -H 'Referer: https://www.host.com/' \
    -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
    -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' \
    -H 'Connection: close'
    
    set -- "$@" \
--data-binary '{"mount":25,"Method":"SA","redirectUrlKo":"https://www.host.com/ricarica?esito=KO","redirectUrlOk":"https://www.host.com/ricarica?esito=OK","toMsisdn":'\""$dyn_param"\"',"txReqDescription":"scarica Online"}'

 httpcode=$(curl -o curl_tmp_dump -w "%{http_code}" "$@" https://api.host.com/api/recharge/public/init 2>/dev/null)
 [ "$httpcode" -eq 200 ] && \cat curl_tmp_dump >> "$output"
\rm -f curl_tmp_dump

done < numbers.txt

exit 0
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130154/discussion-on-answer-by-cbhihe-script-n-curl-posts-from-n-lines-of-txt-file-co).

Comment: @lawrence: what is "$dyn" ? (It's not defined; it should be quoted; it makes `curl_tmp_dump` useless since you don't save your result anymore per your requirement. ???

Comment: @I just abbreviated the palceholder from 'dyn_param' to 'dyn' and forgot to change it here. Anyway I don't like how this website allows to change the original user post and title because my requirement was not to cat the results but instead to echo the single line which returned code '200 OK' and I tough you understood it by now.